# Creating web service dll in C#

Tags: c#, web-services, dll

i have a problem about creating web service dll(class library).

[image]

http://m1306.hizliresim.com/1b/w/pnyv3.png

In this picture, i have to put red cross items into one dll.

Muhendis.mdf which is DATABASE connection
All of DataClasses1.dbml directory and also,
AssemblyInfo.cs

These items should be created in dll.

How can i do that?

Thanks.

Comment: ASMX web services have been replaced by WCF - I'd recommend switching, unless you have a prevailing reason not to.

Answer (score 0):

create classlibrary for your data access items and use the reference of that library in web service.